# Custom rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I need to do some URL Rewriting, but that is all new to me and I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work. For example: I have an URL that looks like this.

```
http://example.com/directorio/?filter=all&search_text=&type=medicos&location=quito&cs_directory_search_location=Yes&search_view=&goe_location_enable=No&cs_loc_max_input=5&cs_loc_incr_step=1&submit=&action=cs_directory_map_search
```

And I wanna make it look like:

```
http://example.com/directorio/medicos/quito/
```

I've tried something like this directly into my `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteRule ^directorio/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?pagename=directorio&filter=all&search_text=&type=$1&location=$2&cs_directory_search_location=Yes&search_view=&goe_location_enable=No&cs_loc_max_input=5&cs_loc_incr_step=1&submit=&action=cs_directory_map_search [L]
```

That doesn't work. Also tried...

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrites' );
function my_custom_rewrites(){

    add_rewrite_tag( '%filter%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%search_text%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%type%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%location%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%cs_directory_search_location%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%search_view%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%goe_location_enable%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%cs_loc_max_input%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%cs_loc_incr_step%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%submit%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%action%', '([^/]+)' );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'directorio/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=directorio&filter=all&search_text=&type=$matches[1]&location=$matches[2]&cs_directory_search_location=Yes&search_view=&goe_location_enable=No&cs_loc_max_input=5&cs_loc_incr_step=1&submit=&action=cs_directory_map_search',
        'top' );
}
```

I also read a bit about query vars, but as I said before, it is a theme we bought and it accesses all the variables in the query string using `$_GET` and not `get_query_var`...

I'm not sure what's the problem there, but I'm out of ideas, it's a tough way to start learning `RewriteRules`. Hoping someone can help.

Hi @Milo, thanks for your answer, one more thing, I have my site live and also the same site on my localhost to test changes before uploading them. The thing is, in my localhost, I edited my .htaccess directly and used this rule.

```
RewriteRule ^directorio/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php/directorio/?filter=all&search_text=&type=$1&location=$2&cs_directory_search_location=Yes&search_view=&goe_location_enable=No&cs_loc_max_input=5&cs_loc_incr_step=1&submit=&action=cs_directory_map_search [L]
```

And that rule, with that ugly url, works perfect, but If I put that same rule on the live site it doesn't work at all. Also, if on that live site, if I use that same rule, but with the absolute path, I get the redirect with no problems, it just wont let me do the `Rewrite`. Is it possible that my hosting has some configuration on the Apache server causing that problem?

Comment: If the code accesses `$_GET`, you will need to populate `$_GET` manually from the WordPress query vars set in your rewrite rules. Despite looking like a query string, WordPress doesn't set any request globals from that string in `add_rewrite_rule`.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your `.htaccess`, in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)filter=all&search_text=&type=(.*)&location=(.*)&cs_directory_search_location=Yes&search_view=&goe_location_enable=No&cs_loc_max_input=5&cs_loc_incr_step=1&submit=&action=cs_directory_map_search
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directorio/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]
```

You can confirm the logic through this [`.htaccess` tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/). Your default `.htaccess` created from WordPress should now look like the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)filter=all&search_text=&type=(.*)&location=(.*)&cs_directory_search_location=Yes&search_view=&goe_location_enable=No&cs_loc_max_input=5&cs_loc_incr_step=1&submit=&action=cs_directory_map_search
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directorio/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have one question, does that Redirection works with regular expressions? It says, it does but I can't get it working. If you could help me with an example on how to do it, it would be great.  Also, putting the redirection directly into my         .htaccess doesn't work either.

Comment: @DysanG. Yes it does. Make sure that you check off the "_Regular expression_" checkbox when adding your rules. I've updated my answer. Check if that works.

Comment: no luck, the plugin works great with plain redirection, but as soon as I activate Regular Expression options it doesn't, the regex query is fine, but the plugin is still trying to make a plain redirection.

Comment: @DysanG. Figured it out, check out my updated and and please confirm.

Comment: Hi Ethan, thanks for your help, but that's not working either, I'm gonna have to take the long road and rewrite the code to generate the urls I want directly.

Comment: @DysanG. Did you clear your website's cache? I know that the `.htaccess` rules may take a few minutes for it to work based on the server. Also, if you're going to take the long road and edit your code, I'd recommend looking into the [Find And Replace Tool](https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/) which is very effective in replacing information in multiple files. I've used it myself and it has saved me a lot of time. Let em know how that goes.